# Git commit signing GPG issue

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, gnupg, git-extensions

I am having the following issue when I am trying to create a commit using Git Extensions and SourceTree

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" commit -F 
"C:\Code\XXX\.git\COMMITMESSAGE"
gpg: keyblock resource 'C:/Code/XXX/%appdata%/gnupg/pubring.kbx': No 
such file or directory
gpg: skipped "ZZZZZZZZZZ": No secret key
gpg: signing failed: No secret key
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
Done
```

My `pubring.kbx` exists in my %appdata% directory but why is it prefixing the repo path to it?

This is on a windows machine FYI.  I have this working on another windows machine but can't figure out what is different here

Comment: I suspect you have `%appdata%` in your `.git/config` and git doesn't expand it. You need to put the full path there.

Comment: @phd there is no mention of `%appdata%` in my git config files, is there anywhere else I should look?

Comment: `git config --list --show-origin`

Comment: A very similar question is now answered here: [gpg: keyblock resource pubring.kbx not found because the repo path is prefixed to the gnupg home](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52661839/gpg-keyblock-resource-pubring-kbx-not-found-because-the-repo-path-is-prefixed-t)